# How to inject text into the beginning of a textfield?

Tags: 7, entities, rules, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site with 3 languages where only 1 field (Description) is really multilingual, everything else is a translated interface and strings.

For the Description field, it has been my aim to replicate the functionality of Wordpress's "qTranslate" plugin so that the UI looks something like this:
[image]

I have almost managed to achieve this using [Fieldgroup](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module, 3 description fields, and [Language Sections](https://drupal.org/project/language_sections) module (because I found no better way to assign each field to its language).

So far so good. But at the top of each field I have to put in default texts (=fr  =en= =el=) so that Language Sections module knows which field is which language and displays the correct text depending on which is the current language.  If the end-users delete those =en= and =fr= tags, then the whole thing falls apart.

So I need a module that will inject those =fr= and =en= tags at the beginning of each textfield's entered text, in a way that's completely transparent to the user. Is there such a module?  Can Rules achieve a functionality like this?

Alternatively, if there is no such module, how would one go about creating one? Which function or which hook to use?

---

**UPDATE**
I made this module called language_markers based on the answer given by *Beebee* ,but it didn't work. Can you pleasetellmewhat I'mdoing wrong? :

```
<?php

function language_markers_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'property_for_sale_node_form' || $form_id == 'property_to_rent_node_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'language_markers_submit_handler_function';
  }
}

function language_markers_submit_handler_function($form, &$form_state) {
  foreach($form_state['values'] as $field_name => $value) {
    switch($field_name) {
      case 'field_description_fr':
        $value = '=fr= '.$value;
        break;
      case 'field_description_nl':
        $value = '=nl= '.$value;
        break;
      case 'field_description_en':
        $value = '=en= '.$value;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**
I have managed to get this to work with Rules module:

***Event:*** After updating existing content of type Property for Sale

***Condition:*** none

***Action:*** Set a data value Parameter: Data: [node:field-description-en..., Value: =en= [node:field-description-en:value]

It works,but when the end-user comes back to edit the node, he sees "=en=" in front of his text. That's a BAD User-Experience. 
This is a work-around, not a solution. I still need a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by invisible text? HTML `<input>` is what it is and it does not support locking and hiding parts of it.

Comment: @Mołot =en= or =ru= are the tags that get filtered out by Language Sections module, which uses them to determine the language of the subsequent text and display the text incorrect language.  Therefore, I want those =en= and =fr= texts to be stored in the database, but not visible to the end user.

Comment: I've removed the word 'invisible' from the question because I think that was confusing things a bit. Could you review those small changes and make sure it still represents what you need to know? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Clive ,I was beginning to wonder why people are voting down my question :) - it is not a stupid question.  Yes, your changes are fine.  By "invisible" I meant "automated" and also in away that the end-users won't be able to see when they come back to edit the node.

Comment: Un-downvoted, now it makes sense to me. Usually invisible means `style="display: none"` or something analogous when talking HTML. Automated is a whole different story.

Answer (score 2):

Do your fields have a different field name per language? For example, maybe they follow some sort of convention like `field_description_en`, `field_description_cn`, `field_description_de`?

If so, then perhaps you can use `hook_form_alter` and add your own submit handler into the form like so :

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'mytype_node_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_submit_handler_function';
  }
}
```

Then create a function `my_custom_submit_handler_function($form, &$form_state)`. Inside the function you'll need to loop through `$form_state['values']` like so and just append your language strings before the values:

```
function my_custom_submit_handler_function($form, &$form_state) {
  foreach($form_state['values'] as $field_name => &$value) { // <-- forgot the & here... oops
    switch($field_name) {
      case 'description_en':
        $value = '=en='.$value;
        break;
      case 'description_cn':
        $value = '=cn='.$value;
        break;
      case 'description_de':
        $value = '=de='.$value;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

There's probably better ways to do it though.

---

**Update**

@drupalina I forgot to put the ampersand on the submit handler function which would have updated $form_state. Here's your code with a working version:

```
<?php

function language_markers_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'property_for_sale_node_form' || $form_id == 'property_to_rent_node_form') {
    // You can remove the texts here too. Below is just an example.
    // Path inside $form may not be correct, so
    // do a var_dump($form) or dpm($form, 'form'); to check the array
    // To use dpm() you need to install "devel" module and enable it.
    #dpm($form, 'form');

    // Trim =fr= string from left side of the #value
    $form['field_description_fr']['#value'] = ltrim($form['field_description_fr']['#value'], '=fr=');
    // You might need to set the #default_value too
    $form['field_description_fr']['#default_value'] = ltrim($form['field_description_fr']['#default_value'], '=fr=');

    // Do this for each language... 
    // $form['field_description_de']['#value'] = .......


    $form['#submit'][] = 'language_markers_submit_handler_function';
  }
}

function language_markers_submit_handler_function($form, &$form_state) {
  // Note the ampersand before $value below, which allows the
  // modifications on $value to persist into $form_state
  foreach($form_state['values'] as $field_name => &$value) {
    switch($field_name) {
      case 'field_description_fr':
        $value = '=fr= '.$value;
        break;
      case 'field_description_nl':
        $value = '=nl= '.$value;
        break;
      case 'field_description_en':
        $value = '=en= '.$value;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

In my opinion, this would quickly turn very unmaintainable as you get more and more fields & languages combinations. So if you are planning to have more than these description fields, I would suggest to use more general ways to find these fields and automatically remove/add the language strings. For example, using [`hook_field_attach_presave`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_presave/7)

Comment: Good answer, actually made me realise what the question was really asking :) I think you could probably do it with rules too, and also `hook_field_presave()`, `hook_node_update()`, `hook_entity_update()`, etc. Plenty of different places this code could go, the form submit handler seems like as good a place as any

Comment: @Beebee thanks for the code!  Indeed, my 3 textarea fields are named field_description_fr field_description_nl field_description_en . I understand that I will need to create a module out of the first code, but where do I put the second code. Since I'm not much of a coder could you please rewrite your code as a module called "language_markers" for the forms IDs property_for_sale_node_form and property_to_rent_node_form   . I REALLY appreciate your help!

Comment: @Beebee I have updated my question with a custom module based on what you wrote, but it didn't work: the Language Sections module doesn't come into effect the way that it would  if I actually had "=en=" and "=fr=" inside the textarea. I also tried both 'field_description_en' and 'description_en'. Can you please help?

Comment: @drupalina check the updated answer. Sorry for late update I usually don't login to d.se on weekends :)